# Flickr as third party to store photos and comments

Tags: flickr

I want to my app photos on flickr. User will upload photos like profile picture etc. to my app which is send to my flickr upgraded account.Basically flickr is used to store images. I have checked api documents. But when I tried to get frob I'm getting "frob invalid" error message. How we can solve this problem

Code is :

```
 public function flickrAction()
    {

        $flickr= new \Flickr_Flickr("bd128b758ad4c379e71gf9e1848e708602","ghghghg");

        $a=$flickr->auth_getFrob ();


        $token=$flickr->auth_getToken ($a);

}
```

and using lib [php-flickr-lib]: https://github.com/blat/php-flickr-lib

Comment: I thik code is not needed. Just calling "flickr.auth.getFrob" api which return "Frob". but if we used that frob to get token it is throwing "frob invalid" error message. I think it is irrespective of code

Comment: Actually it needs user authentication, callback procedure

Comment: nice one.I'm using php flickr lib I have to call just its methods

Comment: flickr->auth_getFrob () method is giving frob. but if we try same frob to get token ...it will show as invalid.